# How to filter data after data is fetched in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, fetch

I'm new in React. I'm try to filter data after this data will received.
I have select tag with options and I want to change data array after select will changed.
For example if selected option will have value 'crypto' show array only with type 'crypto'
Thanks for answer

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


const Fetch = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const [currency, setCurrency] = useState('crypto');
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchange_rates')
            .then((res) => { return res.json() })
            .then((res) => { setData(res.rates); setIsLoaded(true); console.log(res); })
    }, [])


    if (!isLoaded) {
        return <h2>Waiting for data...</h2>
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="currency">Choose currency: </label>
                <select id='currency' onChange={setCurrency}>
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="crypto">Crypto</option>
                    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
                    <option value="commodity">Commodity</option>
                </select>

                {Object.values(data).map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <h3>{item.name}({item.unit}) : <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{item.value}</span></h3>
                            <p>type: {item.type} </p>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                    )
                })}

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Fetch;
```

If statement not working

Comment: What exactly is not working with the if statement? Please specify the problem that occurs.

Comment: How to make filter?
For example if tag select have value 'crypto' return array with 'crypto'. When I'm try to make something like filter looks a have error that says that can't filter data underfiend. I'm understand that I need first to wait data and after filter it but I don't know how

Comment: use react query, `npm i @tanstack/react-query`

Comment: Can we do it with native way? Without any extra libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter data in JavaScript, you may use the `filter` function:

```
Object.values(data)
      .filter(item => item?.type === currency)
      .map(...)
```

Pass a function of your choice that returns either `true` or `false` for each value in the array.

If you want more details, you can find them [in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Not working. When I select any value returns nothing. Just white screen

Comment: I just noticed that there is another problem in your code. The `onChange` function of your `select` does not work that way. It should rather be `onChange={event => setCurrency(event.target.value)}`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix your `onChange` handler this returns a [React ChangeEvent](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/responding-to-events#adding-event-handlers). Currently you're setting the state to the event instead of the selected value. For this you'll also need to add a `value` prop to make the select element a [controlled input](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components#controlled-and-uncontrolled-components).

```js
<select
  id="currency"
  onChange={() => setCurrency(e.target.value)}
  value={currency}
>
  ...
</select>
```

For the filtering you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
{
  Object.values(data)
    .filter((item) => item.type === currency)
    .map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <h3>
            {item.name}({item.unit}) :{" "}
            <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{item.value}</span>
          </h3>
          <p>type: {item.type} </p>
          <hr />
        </div>
      );
    });
}
```